# Error when running flutter pub run build_runner build --delete-conflicting-outputs

Tags: flutter, web3dart

I'm trying to integrate a smart contract into my flutter and I'm referring to [this example](https://zfinix.medium.com/flutter-web3-smart-contract-interaction-in-dart-5669595a0068). I have included all the dependencies and dev_dependencies in the first step and I'm stuck in the second step where this error occurs where the **system could not find the path to `builders.dart` in the web3dart package.** [image: error pic]

Answer (score 0):

**After updating Flutter to version 2.5.2, there were some conflicts even though no code was changed, therefore I use `any` in pubspec.yaml**.

```
 dependencies:
      flutter:
        sdk: flutter
      moor: ^4.5.0
      provider: ^5.0.0
      path_provider: any
      path: ^1.8.0
    
    dev_dependencies:
      flutter_test:
        sdk: flutter
      moor_generator: any
      build_runner: any
      flutter_launcher_icons: any
```

Comment: Still the same. I think my main problem is **System could not find the path to builders.dart in the web3dart package.**

Comment: May be https://flutteragency.com/how-to-solve-pub-run-build_runner-build-failed-in-flutter/ follow this

Answer (score 0):

For me, I had to downgrade to web3dart: ^2.3.5 from ^2.4.1 (pubspec.yaml)

Ran flutter pub get

But the web3dart-2.4.1 folder remained in .../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/

The problem was that build_runner was still looking in the 2.4.1 folder

So I removed everything from the .../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/web3dart-2.4.1 folder and moved everything from the .../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/web3dart-2.3.5 folder into the .../flutter/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/web3dart-2.4.1 folder

Closed Android Studio

Reopened it and ran flutter pub run build_runner build

And it worked

CAUTION: DO NOT RUN FLUTTER PUB UPDATE BEFORE RUNNING FLUTTER PUB RUN BUILD_RUNNER BUILD

When I ran flutter pub update, it pulled a completed different web3dart version (2.4.0) into .../pub.dartlang.org/, which has the same bug in it.

Your folder version may be different, but if you can get the web3dart-2.3.5 version and find which folder build_runner is looking in (by running it in Terminal and reading the error message), you can put the good code into there and it should work